# getDefaultSharedPreferences(...) doesn't work in first run without existed cache

Tags: android

I have a `PreferenceActivity` that holds all my app preferences.
When I want to use these preferences in `Main` activity, I use:

```
prefScreen = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String lang = prefScreen.getString("language_list", null);
```

Now, when I do that and run my app as first-run-on-device-ever (without cache), it crashes immediately.
But, if I called the `PreferenceActivity` (using `startActivity()`) at the beginning of `Main` activity, then return to `Main` itself, it runs very well, even if I edited the code and run it again.
The problem happens again if I cleared the cache of the app manually.
Should I call `PreferenceActivity` always at the first run?! Am I missing something?

**NOTE:** I used `Log` to confirm this to myself. Before first run, `prefScreen.contains("language_list")` is always equals to `false`. And after I call `PreferenceActivity`, it becomes `true`.

Comment: post relevant codes .. only 2 line can't describe. Also show logcat error data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call setDefaultValues in Main to set the default values before used

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues (Context context, int resId, boolean readAgain)
```

Comment: You saved my whole week! Thanks. For some reason, I couldn't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The very first run, the preferences donot exist. From what you have posted, your application is crashing because you must be using "lang" and it would be null on the first call.

To get the preferences updated, either you need to call preferences activity which saves the preferences (and have already seen it works with that) or in the Preferences XML file you need to define default values and call setDefaultValues before performing any task that needs preferences.

Hope this helps.