# PreferenceActivity initializing values for get methods without showing

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I'm having a problem with my PrefernceActivity class.
I have created the class with loading the items from a xml file by calling addPreferencesFromResources(R.xml.settings);

The activity itself works perfectly, I can set my settings and everything, but in this activity I also want to have getter (static) methods for the values. So I setup my values (which are set when the activity opens), my problem is:
- When I open the application without opening the preferenceActivity it gives a FC
- When I open the application with first opening the preferenceActivity and then the get method it does work.

So I think I'll need a way of creating the activity without showing it (or just initializing the values), if anybody can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What your `logcat` says?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493565/getdefaultsharedpreferences-doesnt-work-in-first-run-without-existed-cache/16493590#16493590